# Using BindingSource with data from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, data-binding

I have UserControls with labels in them.
Now I want to add those UserControls to my Form and bind the text of the labels to the data inside my XML file using BindingSource.
I managed to bind the XML data with my labels using this **code**:

```
//Code inside Form class    

private const string path = @"Z:\ak\Dateien\Artikelliste.xml";

private void ArtikelAuflisten()
{
     //Add UserControls and give them XElement
     XElement xmlArtikelliste = XElement.Load(path);
     List<ArtikelAuflistungEinkaufsladen> ucArtikel = new List<ArtikelAuflistungEinkaufsladen>();

     foreach (var p in xmlArtikelliste.Descendants("Artikel"))
     {
          ArtikelAuflistungEinkaufsladen.SetArtikel = p;
          ucArtikel.Add(new ArtikelAuflistungEinkaufsladen());
          this.Controls.Add(ucArtikel[artikelAnzahl - 1]);
     }
}

//Code inside UserControl class

private static XElement _artikel;
public static XElement SetArtikel
{
    set { _artikel = value; }
}

private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
public void ArtikelAuflistungEinkaufsladen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Add XElement to BindingSource
     bs.DataSource = typeof(ArtikelListe);
     bs.Add(new ArtikelListe(_artikel.Element("Name").Value, double.Parse(_artikel.Element("Preis").Value), int.Parse(_artikel.Element("Anzahl").Value)));
            
     //Bind labels
     labelArtikelNr.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "ArtikelID");
     labelName.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "ArtikelName");
     labelPreis.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "ArtikelPreis");
}
```

**XML** structure:

```
<ArtikelListe>
  <Artikel ID="1">
    <Name>Weisswurst 300g</Name>
    <Preis>3,29</Preis>
    <Anzahl>10</Anzahl>
  </Artikel>
  <Artikel ID="2">
    <Name>Käse Alpenreife 275g</Name>
    <Preis>2,33</Preis>
    <Anzahl>12</Anzahl>
  </Artikel>
</ArtikelListe>
```

But **the problem** is that my labels don't update if I change the data inside my XML file. How can I fix that? And is there a better way to create the binding?

Comment: It is easier to bind to a dataset : DataSet ds = new DataSet();ds.ReadXml(path);

Comment: @jdweng I used DataSet instead of DataSource but the problem of my labels not updating when the XML file changes still remains.

Comment: Controls don't automatically repaint when the DataSource is changed so the trick is to set to null and then back to the datasource : label1.datasource = null; label1.datasource = MySource.